# Symfony2: Newsletter Subscription

Tags: symfony, newsletter, fosuserbundle

I need to get the newsletter subscription thing working. The logic i am using is when the user submits his email, i check if there is already a user registered to the site with the email. If yes, i check if he is subscribed to newsletter and do the appropriate subscription. If the email is not in the registered user list, then i have a newsletter table for anonymous users. I check here if he is subscribed or not and do the necessary action.

Here is my controller action code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/newsletter/", name="site_newsletter")
 * @return array
 */
public function newsletterSubscriptionAction(httpRequest $request)
{  
    $email = $request->request->get('email');

    try {

        $email = $request->request->get('email');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT u FROM MyBundle:User u WHERE u.email = :email'
        )->setParameter('email', $email);

        $user = $query->getSingleResult();

        if(!is_object($user)){ //this means anonymous user not registered to site
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT n FROM MyBundle:Newsletter n WHERE n.email = :email AND n.isSubscribed = 1'
            )->setParameter('email', $email);

            $record = $query->getSingleResult();

            if($record){
                $msg = "You are already subscribed!";
            }else{
                $newsletter = new Newsletter();
                $newsletter->setEmail($email);
                $newsletter->setIsSubscribed(true);

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($newsletter);
                $em->flush();

                $msg = "You have been subscribed to our newsletter! Thank You.";
            }
        }else{
            if($user->getNewsletterSubscription()){
                $msg = "You are already subscribed!";
            }else{
                $user->setNewsletterSubscription(1);
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->flush();                    
                $msg = "You have been subscribed to our newsletter! Thank You.";
            }                
        }

    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        $msg = 'Some problem occured. Please try again later';
    }

    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response($msg);
        return array('msg' => $msg);
    }

}
```

I am using ajax to call this controller action. This isn't working. The data m getting back to the ajax is redirected login page.

I am using FOSUSerBundle by the way to manage users. Is this causing any issue? Whats the best way to implement it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to give anon users permission to use your subscription route.

In your security.yml file, add something like:

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/subscribe, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: Hey.  Pushed me over 2000 reps.  Thanks.